# What is a "human act" in Catholic moral theology?

Tags: catholicism, morality

What is a "human act" in Catholic moral theology, and how does it relate to "full consent of the will" which is one of the conditions for a mortal sin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Human acts

Prümmer, O.P., [*Handbook of Moral Theology*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7258) pp. 7-8:

> 9. Three definitions which do not differ essentially from each other are usually given: **a *human act is one which proceeds from the deliberate will of man***; or, *an act which **proceeds from the knowledge of the intellect and the impulse of the will***; or, ***an act of which man himself is the master***.
>
> Therefore the following acts are not human:
>
> 1. Acts *which proceed from the vegetative faculty in man*, such as nutrition, the pulse of the heart, etc. For man is not the master of such acts, since they do not proceed from his intellect and will.
> 2. Acts elicited by those who are completely mad, by drunkards, by children without the use of their reason, by those under hypnotic influence. Such acts are not directed by a deliberate will.
> 3. The so-called "*actus primo-primi*" which occur so quickly that they precede the use of the reason and will, such as those sudden feelings of anger which arise from an unexpected insult. On the other hand those acts which are called "*secundo-primi*" and "*secundo-secundi*" are human acts, although the former are not so perfect as the latter through lack of complete attention.
> 4. *Forced* acts which are performed under the influence of external violence. Man is not the master of such acts.

## Full consent & mortal sin

[*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7258) p. 69:

> Three conditions must be verified for mortal sin:
>
> 1. There must be *grave matter* which is determined by the object and circumstances of the act (or omission) and which is made known to us as such in the first place through the teaching authority of the Church and her theologians. There are some sins which do not admit of slight matter and these are mortal sins "*ex toto genere suo*" (v.g., lust, blasphemy, etc.); in other sins the matter is not always grave (v.g., in theft, or fasting), and thus the sin may be venial. These are mortal sins "*ex genere suo*".
> 2. *Full advertence* to the moral nature of the act is required. Therefore where such advertence is defective, sins are always venial (or there may be no sin at all) because of the act's imperfection.
> 3. ***Full consent* is also necessary, and this is always presumed to be present where there is full advertence and no external violence. Therefore fear and passion certainly diminish consent but do not destroy it, and they do not prevent mortal sin unless full advertence is lacking.**
>
> <sup>In practice there is often reasonable doubt whether all these three conditions were verified or not in a particular case. In such instances, if the confessor fails to reach a conclusion after prudent enquiry he must leave the matter to God's judgement but warn the penitent against future dangers of sinning. If the penitent is in doubt about one or other of the requisite conditions he should candidly reveal his doubts to the confessor and submit to his judgement.</sup>
>
> <sup>In the following instances *advertence and consent are imperfect*:
> 1. when an act is committed while half asleep or half drunk;
>
> 2. when the penitent is not in complete possession of himself, v.g., because of a sudden and most vehement surge of passion;
>
> 3. when a person is suffering from pathological states or feelings, e.g., hysteria, mania, phobia;
>
> 4. when the penitent can truthfully and certainly assert that he would never have acted in that way if he had thought about it seriously beforehand;
>
> 5. when the penitent in the face of temptation is immediately agitated and sorry because of the devout state of his conscience.</sup>

Comment: @KenGraham That was not done arbitrarily. We came to the conclusion that my original question can be reduced to this one, so it is helpful.

Comment: @Geremia The answer is good, but it is still unclear how is concept of "human act" related to the concept of "full consent". I pose two questions. (1): Let us call some action x. The central question seems to be: if x is a human act, does that mean that x was done with full consent? (2): It seems that you say that what is meant by *full consent* is just the same as voluntary. Is that so?

Comment: @Thom Okay and understood!

Comment: @Thom "_if x is a human act, does that mean that x was done with full consent?_" According to Prümmer, "forced acts" (i.e., non human acts) done under "fear and passion certainly diminish consent but do not destroy it," "unless full advertence is lacking."

Comment: @Thom "_what is meant by full consent is just the same as voluntary_"? And, in addition, done with full advertance.

Comment: @Geremia You say: >> "forced acts" (i.e., **non human acts**) done under "fear and passion certainly diminish consent but do not destroy it," "unless full advertence is lacking." <<, but how can non human acts be done with any degree consent? Isn't consent something that makes a human act?

Comment: @Thom Full consent is a condition for mortal sin, not "something that makes a human act".

Comment: @Geremia If *full consent* = *full advertence + voluntary*, then why is full advertence counted as a **separate condition** for mortal sin (would it not be then sufficient to say that the mortal sin is one which is committed with *full consent* and where *grave matter* is present)?

Comment: @Geremia You say: >>Full consent is a condition for mortal sin, not "something that makes a human act".<< Consent is *some kind of a choice in view of some end*, isn't that a distinctly human act?

Comment: @Thom Condition #2 has to do with the intellect, and Condition #3 with the will. (The will follows the intellect.) Condition #3 is required ∵ sin is voluntary. If there were no #3, then I could, e.g., be forced to commit adultery, despite my knowing "the moral nature of the act".

Comment: @Thom A human act "proceeds from the knowledge of the intellect **and** the impulse of the will" or one which "proceeds from the **deliberate** will of man". A human act requires both intellect and will. Consent only has to do with the will.

Comment: @Thom Perhaps you're asking why the conditions for mortal sin aren't two: (1) grave matter (2) human act? Because one must know the act is a grave offense against God.

Comment: @Geremia Okay that makes sense. You say >>Perhaps you're asking why the conditions for mortal sin aren't: (1) Grave matter; (2) human act?<< Yes, I ask precisely that.

Comment: @Thom Prümmer is solidly Thomistic. He knows [Thomistic Thesis](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm) #21: "The will follows, does not precede, the intellect; …" (_Intellectum sequitur, non præcedit, voluntas…_).

Comment: To conclude, just so that I can be sure I understood correctly, a mortal sin is a human act whose matter is grave and done with the knowledge that the act is gravely offensive to God (we could use this as an alternative definition). Also, thanks for having patience for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how one got into the situation of "sleep[ing] with someone other then his husband or wife". If it's an [indirectly willed act](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/63540/1787) (e.g., one lost his ability to make informed decisions, such as by getting drunk; cf. [§94](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/35354/pg35354-images.html#id00295) of [*Moral Theology*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5547)), then this adultery certainly is a [formal sin](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33615). If one was tricked into it (as Jacob was with Lia in [Gen. 29:23](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=29&l=23-#x)-25), then it is only a [material sin](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34791) of adultery.

Comment: I am not speaking about something which is only materially sinful. That is not an act of adultery properly speaking. I am interested only in adultery as a formal sin.

Comment: @Thom "_I am interested only in adultery as a formal sin._" Then why do you speak of a "human act […] being done without full consent"? Aren't those involuntary acts? There is no sin in involuntary acts.

Comment: Does the: x is a human act of the person y imply y did x with the full consent?

Comment: **Objection**: It would seem that the human act can be done without full consent. Theologians do not waste words. That implies that the consent can exist without being full, i.e. it can be partial. Now, since a human act is that which aims to attain something formally, then the partial consent is sufficient since that which is consented to is in some way formally aimed.

Comment: @Thom "_It would seem that the human act can be done without full consent._" Yes. Aren't those involuntary acts?

Comment: I don't know (I gave an objection for the negative). For if the x being a human act of y would imply that y did x with full consent then my question would be resolved (so if you can prove that the full consent is implied in an action being a human action, that would suffice to answer my question). Maybe I am just misunderstanding what a *full consent* means and how is it related to the concept of *human act*.